# Visual Studio can not find the latest installed .NET SDK

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, sdk, frameworks

I downloaded a project from Github with its Target Framework `netcoreapp3.1`. After building it, an error stating that

> The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1. Either target .NET Core 2.2 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1.

Hence, I downloaded and installed `dotnet-sdk-3.1.300-win-x64` and now my SDK list is the following:

```
dotnet --list-sdks
2.1.602 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.700 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.801 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

In the environment variables, I added a new variable for the Path User variables pointing to `C:\Program Files\dotnet\`.

However, Visual Studio still outputs the same error in regards to the .NET SDK's version. If I go to the project's Properties, all previous 4 SDK versions appear, except for the 3.1 one.
[image]
Is there any workaround fix for this or shall I just reinstall Visual Studio?

Comment: Thank you! My VS is indeed older than 16.6 - it's 16.2.2. I will update it and see if that works!

Comment: have you tried the last 16.6 version? Does it solve the issue?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Sorry for the delayed answer! Yes, it did solve the issue, indeed! Thank you very much!

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer, so that you can [accept the reply as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to "close" the question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67049414/the-latest-installed-net-sdk-not-found/67049415 which is the MS supported answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To target .Net Core 3.1 with the [SDK 3.1.300](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1) you Visual Studio 2019 Update 6 (16.6):

[image]

So, run [Visual Studio Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#use-the-visual-studio-installer) and install the offered 16.6 update.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio won't be able to find the latest SDK if it's a different bit size than the first SDK installation. To fix that case see [Windows or Visual Studio can't find the latest installed .NET SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67049414/windows-cant-find-the-latest-installed-net-sdk)