# Windows or Visual Studio 2022 can't find the latest installed .NET SDK due to bitness

Tags: .net, windows, .net-core, dotnet-sdk

I've successfully installed the latest .NET SDK, but Windows doesn't recognize it. This is manifested by one of the following failures:

- `dotnet --list-sdks`  doesn't include the latest .NET SDK.
- Windows x64 can't find .NET 5, .NET 6, or .NET 7.
- Visual Studio can't find the latest SDK or throws one of the following errors when trying to open a project:

  - > Project 'MyProject' load failed: The specified SDK "Microsoft.NET.Sdk" was not found.
  - > Unable to locate the .NET SDK. Check that it is installed and that the version specified in global.json (if any) matches the installed version
  - > The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET N.N. Either target .NET N.M or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET N.N

How can I get Windows to recognize the latest installed version of the .NET SDK?

Answer (score 61):

Run `where dotnet` from the command line. If the output is similar to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
```

Then both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the SDK have been installed at some time.

```
32 bit --- C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe
64 bit --- C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
```

The first SDK installed on the computer puts the dotnet path in the system path. Any subsequent SDK install of a different bit size SDK also adds dotnet path to the system path, but after the first dotnet path. Therefore, only SDK's of the first bit size are available by default, using the `path` variable.

There are two approaches to fixing the problem:

1. Install the latest SDK with the other bit size. This is the easiest solution.
2. Change the order of `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe` and `C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe` in the System  environment variables path:

Select the windows key and enter `Edit`, then select **Edit the system variables**
[image]

Select the **Environment Variables** button on the **Advanced** tab:

[image]

Select the **Path** > **Edit** under **System variables** (not User variables).

[image]

Find the entries for `C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe` (64 bit) and `C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe` (32 bit)  and using the **Move** up button, change to order. Here's an example:

[image]

Select the **OK** button until all the windows are closed. Open a new command prompt and run where dotnet.

Answer from https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/5962
More details at https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Apr/20/Adventures-in-NET-SDK-Installation-SDKs-not-Showing-Up

Comment: In my case the where command did not present anything and it seems that Visual Studio 2019 simply did not add the `C:\Program Files\dotnet` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet` file paths to my System Path Environment Variable. So, the second part of your solution was applicable. Thank you!

Comment: Keeping my fingers crossed but it looks like the 17.7.1 update works out of the box
No more messing around with environment variables

Comment: @plykkegaard I raised this bug internally long ago and was promised they'd eventually fix it. Hopefully it's fixed now.

Comment: I can confirm it is fixed for now, I haven't had the issue the last couple of updates, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changing the order of the environmental variables as suggested above did the trick. By moving c:\programfiles\dotnet up and moving it above c:\programfiles(x86)\dotnet solved the problem. This solution also solve the problem for the following error:
"The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found." in Visual Studio