# Not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs on Windows 11 (visual Studio code)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, windows-11

I very recently upgraded to Windows 11, I am not sure if this is the source of the issue though.

My proccess:

1. Installed .NET 5.0 SDK (v5.0.402) - Windows x64 Installer
2. Opened Visual Studio Code (Version 1.61.2)
3. Downloaded Extension (C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp))
4. After instalation I recieve the following notification (It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs)

TroubleShooting steps taken:

1. Through command prompt located dotnet.

   [
   C:\Users\tim>where.exe dotnet
   C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe
   C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
   ]
2. Restarted Computer
3. Uninstalled/Reinstalled .NET
4. Uninstalled/Reinstaled c# extension
5. My Pc -> settings ->advanced settings ->enviroment variables -> path -> dotnet is not listed, added manually. checked VS still not finding -> Restarted still not finding.

Comment: Should be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67049414/windows-or-visual-studio-cant-find-the-latest-installed-net-sdk-due-to-bitness

Answer (score 8):

I have experienced same thing. This is how I resolved it

- Goto Pc -> settings ->advanced settings ->enviroment variables -> System Variables
- Select & Edit "Path" variable
- Here you will see two different paths for dotnet

  1. C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet
  2. C:\Program Files\dotnet\
- Delete first value. Close the "enviroment variables" windows by clicking "OK"
- Open cmd prompt and type dotnet --info. You'll now see SDK listed on the screen.
- Once you restart your computer, open VS Code, goto terminal and type dotnet --info. You should be good now.

Comment: I haven't done the Windows 11 thing yet, but it's only a matter of time. I always bookmark stuff like this because I know I'll be asking the same question soon enough. Cheers!