# Error create project windows form app in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, desktop

When I create a Windows Forms project (running on the .NET Framework), it works without problems.

But Windows Forms app doesn't work neither in .NET 6.0 nor in .NET 7.0.

In the end, there is always a solution with 0 project and it is not possible to add the project that you create there in the folders.

I am using VS 17.7.1

See this screenshot:

https://pasteboard.co/gSCqZeyFtwCY.gif

.NET SDK 6 and 7 installed
[image: Installed]

Working 
[image]

Comment: Link to the image is broken. BTW: you have to provide more details about issue. And i suggest to use text instead of image.

Comment: @MaciejLos Link works.  It's just a giant gif like video.

Comment: the image is ok

The problem is that it doesn't have more details than the picture
It simply doesn't create the project correctly as you can see

Comment: Please check  .Net6/7 runtime is installed in Visual Studio Installer and try repairing Visual Studio.

Comment: Edited the question with print of installs SDK

Comment: try repairing Visual Studio: I already tried!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding  `C:\Program Files\dotnet\` in System Environment Path.

I am able to reproduce your problem by removing the variable.

Comment: Very good

This link also helped
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67049414/windows-or-visual-studio-2022-cant-find-the-latest-installed-net-sdk-due-to-bi/67049415#67049415

There were 2 environment variables there in the path
I updated with print working