# Can't run code in Visual Studio Community Edition

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I started a course about C#, but when I tried to run the code there was no button, just a button named attach.

I searched online and have found no clue on how to solve this problem.

[image: The Button]

I was expecting to run my code in the Visual Studio Community.

Comment: You're editing a standalone file. You need to create a Project first.

Comment: Here are some [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/csharp-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners/) to get you going. And here's the tutorial that will help you understand Dai's comment, [Working with Code Files, Projects, and Solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/csharp-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners/working-with-code-files-projects-and-solutions). All the best in your adventures :)

Comment: The problem is that it is what shows when i create a Project :/

Comment: Click `Toolbar -> View -> Solution Explorer`. Is there a solution ConsoleApp1?

Comment: Also, please check the environment variable is set: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67049414/windows-or-visual-studio-2022-cant-find-the-latest-installed-net-sdk-due-to-bi/67049415#67049415

Answer (score -1):

**You can execute the code using the C# interactive window if you just want to execute C# code with no project.**

1. Highlight the code you want to run
2. Right click and select- "Execute in C# Interactive"

**To get the buttons you are asking about then you need to add your .CS file to a project. The easiest solution is to create a new project with the option to use existing files.**
Microsoft link : [Create a project from existing code files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/creating-solutions-and-projects?view=vs-2022#create-a-project-from-existing-code-files)
[image: Project from Existing Code]

**You are using top-level statements. See link with explanation of this style vs a "Program.Main" type style program. A lot of examples will use the Program.Main style**
[C# console app template generates top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates)

If you receive an error like :

Error   CS8370  Feature 'top-level statements' is not available in C#
7.3. Please use language version 9.0 or greater.

1. Right click and select quick actions
2. Select Convert to Program.Main style

[image: Convert to Program.Main style]