# Microsoft Visual Studio: The SDK 'microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, msbuild

[Please help me fix this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM8R7.png)

, I already tried to reinstall my Microsoft visual studio and also fixed my environment variables PATH, I've moved up my dotnet including x86 and tools and have restarted my Pc. Also, installed .Net but still my sdk could not be found.

Comment: What version does that .csproj file reference?  Then [check if that SDK is installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/how-to-detect-installed-versions?pivots=os-windows).

Comment: Can you share the text of your .csproj file or at least the first 10-15 lines? It would help to see the type of project and the first `PropertyGroup` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please confirm if `.NET` `SDK` has been checked in `VS Installer > Modify > Individual components > .NET > .NET SDK`. If it isn’t checked, please check it and click Modify.

You could also check if both `x86` and `x64` SDK is installed by running `where.exe dotnet` in cmd.

The first SDK installed on the computer puts the `dotnet` path in the system path. Any subsequent SDK install of a different bit size SDK also adds dotnet path to the system path, but after the first dotnet path. Therefore, only SDK's of the first bit size are available by default, using the path variable.

[Reference:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67049414/windows-or-visual-studio-2022-cant-find-the-latest-installed-net-sdk-due-to-bi/67049415#67049415)

I see a similar issue raised in MS Q/A and resolved. Please check it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1184941/the-sdk-microsoft-net-sdk-specified-could-not-be-f)

I hope this could help.